# What's the chemical reaction between coffee and sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: acid-base, chemical-formula

Every morning I put sodium bicarbonate into my coffee and I was wondering what chemical reaction this produces and what are the chemicals produced at the end.

I cannot find an answer to this question online. I can only find the reaction between chloridric acid and sodium bicarbonate, which is:

NaHCO3 (aq) + HCl (aq) → NaCl (aq) + CO2 (g) + H2O (l)

This produces co2 that makes me burp and burn my throat. This is the exact reason I started putting my sodium bicarbonate into my coffee, rather than my mouth. But I was wondering what is happening now.

Comment: "*I started putting my sodium bicarbonate into my coffee, rather than my mouth.* — That is, you do not take coffee orally?:) Look, coffee contain alkaloids (and caffeine is one of them) that will affects the secretion of hydrochloric acid in your stomach, which would lead to different rate of reaction with baking soda you are drinking with or without coffee. But mixing soda and caffeine alone won't result in a reaction.

Comment: You are not supposed to eat/drink sodium bicarbonate or add it to the coffee? How much do you add? A pinch or a tablespoon?

Comment: Furthermore, $\ce{CO2}$ will never "burn your throat" as you say. Never !

Comment: The reason I put sodium bicarbonate in the cup of coffee (and not directly into my mouth) is that in this way I don't burp for some reasons. From the answer below it seems to understand that the reason I don't burp is because co2 is released in the coffee cup rather than in my stomach. Also, co2 cannot burn my throat but it's a fact every time I start burping my throat start becoming painful and I tend to lose my voice. I suspect the burping due to co2 is bringing up something else from my stomach to my throat. I hope it's more clear now what I mean

Comment: It has only indirect relation to coffee. Coffee is known to trigger reflux of stomach acidic juices ( typically up to 1% HCl ) and bicarbonate acts as antacid. In hot solutions it tends to release half of CO2, forming carbonate. Both react with natural  coffee organic acids and the rest with HCl when they meet. But AFAIK bicarbonate usage as antacid is rather deprecated.

Comment: @user1883212, Please consult a doctor, burning sensation after a burp shows acid reflux from the stomach. Still adding bicarb to coffee is a very bad unhealthy idea.

Comment: @M. Faroow why is adding sodium bicarbonate to coffee unhealthy per se? To the OP, normally one would enjoy a nice coffee then use an anti acid... The right way should be skip coffee, in your case.

Comment: Alchimista, The OP has not shared how much soda bicarb he/she is adding.

Answer (score 2):

Per [a source](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/is-coffee-acidic#variations), to quote:

> Here are the nine major acids in coffee, listed from highest concentration to lowest: chlorogenic, quinic, citric, acetic, lactic, malic, phosphoric, linoleic, and palmitic (3). The brewing process releases acids from coffee beans, giving this beverage a pH of 4.85 to 5.10, which is considered acidic.

As such, the action of Sodium bicarbonate with these acids are examples of neutralization reactions producing the corresponding Sodium salts and releasing carbon dioxide gas.

You may wish to research the possible salts for their respective properties. In particular, the same reference further notes with respect to possible health issues:

> While coffee’s acidity is fine for most people, it may aggravate certain health conditions in others.

> These conditions include acid reflux, gastric ulcers, and irritable bowel syndrome (IBS). Coffee’s effects on these conditions are mainly attributed to its acidity and slight laxative effect in some people (6, 7, 8).

There are also a large number of ascribed benefits of drinking coffee as noted in [this source](https://www.onemedical.com/blog/newsworthy/10-healthy-reasons-to-drink-coffee-2/).

Comment: This may be a good answer to the question how it is presented, but the real issue behind is treatment of stomach reflux and excessive stomach acidity, for which coffee is kind of contradicted. The bicarbonate  is not here to neutralise coffee acids, but as antacid to neutralise stomach HCl.